# Execute a CI controller function via Amazon ec2 cron job

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I am trying to execute a codeigniter controller function via amazon ec2 cron job. I have created a new file in **/etc/cron.hourly** folder. The code of the file is

```
/usr/bin/php -q http://abc/interface/index.php/xyz/xyz_cron_update/a
```

But it's not working. I have followed the "Quick Job Setup" from following link
https://avastechnology.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/creating-a-new-cron-job-on-aws-linux-ami/

What's going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need Some more clarification on what cron job you are running. And for running a cron job in codeigniter better use [CLI](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html).

Then try this in your cron:

```
php path-to-your-app/index.php xyz/xyz_cron_update/a
```